# Get the iframe content of the current tab's web page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am a beginner in chrome extension developing. I am loading a page to browser and it has an iframe. I want to grab the content of that iframe from the extensions. How can I do that? Or if it's not possible is there any alternative to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject a content script into this iframe and get the content from there. You should use attribute: **"all_frames": true**

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.iframe.domain/*"],
      "js": ["js/content-script.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
```